Set manually verified state for VerificationControl Azure B2C custom policy
I have implemented custom DisplayControl based on official tutorial.
It literally looks like below and it works as suggested in tutorial - it always requests from user to verify email address even if email is already verified during sign-up or in edit profile in past. This is not exactly what I want.
Here is sample custom control (same as in tutorial doc):
<DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
  <DisplayClaims>
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"  Required="true" />
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
  </DisplayClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <Actions>
    <Action Id="SendCode">
      <ValidationClaimsExchange>
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendGrid" />
      </ValidationClaimsExchange>
    </Action>
    <Action Id="VerifyCode">
      <ValidationClaimsExchange>
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
      </ValidationClaimsExchange>
    </Action>
  </Actions>
</DisplayControl>

This doesn't work for me because DisplayControl is always in "non verified" state when user lands on Edit Profile page. It means every time when user visit Edit Profile page it will ask user to verify email address again. If user decides to not verify address, in that case saving changes on Edit Profile page will be blocked because "Continue" button is disabled.
I would like to use in Edit Profile user flow with slight modifications:

When user lands to edit profile page, custom display control should be in verified state (always, even if email is never entered)
"Change" button should be displayed for email DisplayControl instead of "Send Verification Code". Users can decide on their own if they want to change email.
User should be able to save changes on edit profile without verification if email value was not changed.

Is there any way to set default value for verified state?

This is more like a comment but I don't have enough points for it. So here goes my answer.
Instead of trying to modify the user data through a custom policy, you could build a HTML page that can make a graph API call to make changes for the particular user. If the user is already signed in, you have the access token and can perform account modification only if the access token is valid. Would there be any challenge implementing this flow?
Edit:
If you already have the user's email address when user clicks 'Edit profile', you could straightaway trigger a custom policy and send the email address in query params using Claim Resolvers. The custom policy could read the object id from the email address and other values from DisplayClaim  and update them directly using a technical profile like AAD-UserWrite...
If this userflow is something you are not familiar with, I could update you further with some code by same time tomorrow.

There are different workarounds to verify email but I would like to implement custom DisplayControl which is UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl" type and be able to verify.

This doesn't work for me because DisplayControl is always in "non verified" state when user lands on Edit Profile page. 
From my experience, this is how the VerificationControl has always worked. I believe it is not possible to start the verification control in 'verified' state.
But do you even need 'VerificationControl' for edit profile page? If you tell me your userflow, I could see how you can accomplish edit profile without using DisplayControl. How many pages are there from where user can end up in 'Edit Profile'? Are all those pages custom policies like signup, forgot pwd?

On second thought, I realize that it doesn't matter where the user ends up from. As long as you have the email address, you could trigger a custom policy that doesn't require VerificationControl but update the user records directly. I've updated my answer on the same
